# Excel flash fill rows automatically to adjacent rows until the next value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet file that looks like this:
[image: Flash fill for adjacent rows]

What I want is to fill the yellow fields with the last value on the left, so for CA it will fill until 26, and NYC until 81 before SG. What's the best way to achieve this, since I have literary hundreds of these?

I have tried using flash fill and paste specials, but they only work for rows downwards, and not for adjacent rows. I also used the Home>Fill series to the right, but then it overlaps another row when I highlight them all (so it shows CA instead of NYC, SG and MC).

Can anybody help me with this problem? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

- select from the cell CA to the last yellow highlighted cell
- hit F5 or Ctrl-G to open the **Go To dialog**
- click the **Special** button
- in the dialog tick **blanks** and hit OK
- now only the empty cells are selected.
- without changing that selection, type a `=` sign
- hit the **left arrow**, this will add a cell reference after the `=` sign
- hold down the **Ctrl** key and hit **Enter**

Now all previously empty cells have a formula that refers to the cell to the left.

If you want, you can select all cells again and use Paste Special > Values to overwrite the formulas with the result.

Comment: worked perfectly well! Thanks so, so much @teylyn! You saved my day! :)